# How can I change &amp to &

Tags: java, soap, cdata

My service method doesn't return & symbol.
My code:

```
    @WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService") public class NewWebService {

        @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
        public String hello() {        
            return "a&b";
        } 
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your method returns the `&` symbol, but your way of checking it is not correct. How do you call your service endpoint and how do you validate the return value?

Comment: For test I use wizdler.

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:helloResponse xmlns:ns2="http://az/">
            <return>a&amp;b</return>
        </ns2:helloResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

Comment: Ok, so it's returning the `&`. But only encoded. As you are using JAX-WS all responses will automatically be XML-encoded. The plain `&` is not valid for XML. Every library used to read the service's response and to parse the returned XML should be able to handle this and to return the unencoded value.

Comment: I can't  return correct symbol(&) in the xml response ?

Comment: You can, but it will be encoded to be returned inside of the XML.

Comment: how can doing ? )

Comment: You **are** already doing it. `&amp;` is the XML-encoded equivalent of `&`. Use some library to parse the XML response and you will get `a&b` as value.

Comment: My xml should return link such as 
http://test.az?a=2&b=3
I just will take this value and go to this link.

Comment: Take a look at the example from oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html) and try to implement a client like it is done in the example.

Comment: I wont to get Link from wizdler.
I won't write client.

Comment: I sow CDATA ,but it doesn't work in my example.

Comment: Perhaps you don't want to use JAX-WS, which is tightly coupled to XML, but instead use a REST-Service (JAX-**RS**) instead. This will give you more options for returning values. Otherwise, good luck.

Comment: I wont to use JAX-WS and I get link value from as wizdler tool.